# Remove timer on change of value in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval

I have the below code in my angular control

```
scope.$watch(function(){ return scope.state; }, function() {
    var t1 = scope.state;
        var Interval = setInterval(function(){ Timer() }, 2500);
        if(t1 != "b"){
            clearInterval(Interval);
        }

        function Timer() {
            console.log(t1);
        }
});
```

My expectation is once t1 becomes "b", timer should stop printing. Unable to understand the reason why t1 keeps printing as if clear interval never happened. If this is wrong what would be the correct way to do.

Comment: because t1 is only checked once... You set the interval and right after you make it you see if the variable is "b" and than that is it. If the variable is not "b" right at that instant it will never be cleared.

Comment: But I have my function in watch, I was thinking t1! = "b" will be verified when ever the $watch of scope.state becomes "b" .

Comment: Read my answer below where I added more details on what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `t1` is only checked once. You set the interval and right after you make it you see if the variable is "b" and than that is it. If the variable is not "b" right at that instant it will never be cleared.

When the watcher is called again, you create a NEW interval and rerun that check. If the variable "b" now, it will kill that interval, it will not do anything to the interval that was created the last time it was called.

You probably want something like this where you only create the interval when it is created for the first time.

```
scope.$watch(function() { return scope.state; }, function() {
  var t1 = scope.state;
  if (!scope.myInterval) {  //if there is no interval create it
    function timer() {
      console.log(t1);
    }
    scope.myInterval = setInterval(timer, 2500);
  }
  if (t1 != "b") {
    clearInterval(scope.myInterval);
    //delete scope.myInterval;
  }

});
```

And since you are using angular, you should probably use their $[interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

And not on scope...

```
var myInterval;
scope.$watch(function() { return scope.state; }, function() {
  var t1 = scope.state;
  if (!myInterval) {  //if there is no interval create it
    function timer() {
      console.log(t1);
    }
    myInterval= setInterval(timer, 2500);
  }
  if (t1 != "b") {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = null;
  }

});
```

Comment: I was trying to set flag on scope and overcome this issue, but defining the function on scope is the way as clearInterval needs to use the same, not of that instance. Even though I had an idea because it is new interval could not overcome it. Declaring on scope is the trick. Thanks

Comment: Well it can be a local variable defined outside, does not need to be part of the scope.